# Is the following identity true?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Calculation suggests the following identity:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{2j-1}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$

I have verified this identity for $n$ up to $5000$ via Maple and find that the left-hand side approaches $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. However, this double summation has slow rate of convergence and I am unsure it is true.

So I want to ask if it is true. If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Let $L$ be your limit.  Numerically, I get $(1-\sqrt{5})/2 < -0.61803 < -0.617 < L$.

Comment: It seems to be $-\pi^2/16$ which is pretty close to $(1-\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: @Lucia ... taking $n=10^5$, I do not disprove the value $-\pi^2/16$.

Comment: Just since this came up on my Close queue:  while the problem may not look research level, very similar double integrals occur in Beukers's proof of irrationality of $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$, which is certainly ``research level" and is what piqued my interest in this (plus the fact that the answer is another pretty constant very close to the one guessed by OP).

Comment: @Lucia: What is the "close queue"? Is this a feature of MO?

Comment: @GHfromMO yes, it is a [review queue](http://mathoverflow.net/review) where more experienced users (with >3k reputation) decide which questions to [close](http://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/close-questions) or leave open.

Comment: Just a comment on the numerical approach: Euler-summation can often improve convergence dramatically. For your problem I arrived with the first 36 partial sums 20 correct digits. Here is the protocol of index and partial sums:$$\small \begin{array} {}...& ...\\33& -0.61685027506808491388 \\
34 &-0.61685027506808491375 \\
35 &-0.61685027506808491370 \\
36 &-0.61685027506808491369 \\
37 &-0.61685027506808491368 \\
38 &-0.61685027506808491368 \\
...& ...\\ \end{array}
$$ *(I used Euler-summation to order 0.58)* With W/A you'd found the correct value easily...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can evaluate this by using generating functions and integrating.  The answer is $-\pi^2/16 = -0.61685 \ldots$ which is pretty close to $(1-\sqrt{5})/2=-0.61803\ldots$.

Here's a sketch: the sum is 
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \int_0^1 (1+x^2+ \ldots +x^{2k-2}) dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{2j} \sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} dx
$$
which is 
$$
 = \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{2j} \Big(\int_0^1 
\sum_{k=j}^{\infty} -(-y)^{k} dy \Big) dx = - \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2 y)^j}{1+y} dy dx,
$$
which is 
$$
 = - \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{dx dy}{(1+x^2y)(1+y)}.  
$$
The integral in $y$ can be done easily: 
$$ 
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2} \Big( \frac{1}{1+y}- \frac{x^2}{1+x^2y}\Big)dy = \log \Big(\frac{2}{1+x^2}\Big) \frac{1}{1-x^2}. 
$$
We're left with 
$$ 
- \int_0^1 \log \frac{2}{1+x^2} \frac{dx}{1-x^2},
$$ 
which WolframAlpha evaluates as $-\pi^2/16$.  (This doesn't look too bad to do by hand, but I don't see a reason to do one variable integrals that a computer can recognize at once.)

Comment: We may do the change of variables $y=z^2$, $xz=t$, we get $2\int_{t<z} dtdz/(1+t^2)(1+z^2)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 dtdz/(1+t^2)(1+z^2)=(\pi/4)^2$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Nicely done!

Comment: Gee you must be good at those Facebook math questions :D

Comment: In the second display line, should the terminal $dy$ on the LHS be $dx$, and is there a missing $dx$ at the end of the line?

Comment: @JohnBentin: Yes, that's right.  Now fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Start with
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right).$$
Since $\frac1{1-z^2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\sum_{n\geq1}z^{2n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}$, we have
$$\int_0^z\left(\sum_{n\geq1}z^{2n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}\right)dz=\int_0^z
\frac1{2(1-z^2)}\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)\,dz.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^{2n}}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}=
\frac18\log^2\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right).$$
Choose $z=i=\sqrt{-1}$ so that
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}=
\frac18\log^2\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}=-\frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$